# jquery fading through different css backgrounds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website and I want an image to change every 5 seconds, it's a css background on a DV. How can I achieve this with JQUERY? I have 3 different images that I want it to fade through and loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
function cycle(imageList) {
  var i = 0;
  var doNext = function() {
    if (i === imageList.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    $('#theId').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageList[i] + ')');
    i++;
  };

  setInterval(function() { doNext(); }, 5000);
}

...
cycle(['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg']);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d4JN9/1/

Comment: @JakeStainer i'm sure there is a way to fade in a CSS attribute with jQuery but I don't know of a way. If you ask that as a separatequsetion though I'm sure that someone will popup with a way to do it.